# How can I reliably determine if a file is an image file?

Tags: shell-script, shell, files, images

Currently I'm using the following command:

```
file image.jpg | cut -d " " -f 2
```

So far so good. It works on a file without an image extension too. So, I was wondering if there's another way to do this? I might have not seen a certain case where the above code would fail.

Edit: I am trying to create a script for renaming the image files in a directory sequentially.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ImageMagick project has facilities to identify images.

I'm using ImageMagick all the time, including its "identify" feature from the command line and it never failed once to identify a picture.

Note that it gives much more than just the format, for example:

```
$  identify tmp3.jpg 
tmp3.jpg JPEG 1680x1050 1680x1050+0+0 DirectClass 8-bit 293.582kb 

$  identify tmp.png
tmp.png PNG 1012x900 1012x900+0+0 DirectClass 8-bit 475.119kb
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `file` is a reliable method for identifying file types. It does not rely on file extensions, but rather on "magic numbers"; the beginning of the file content.

To make your process more robust you can use `libmagic` directly. That way if for some reason the format of `file`'s output changes it won't affect you. However, that does mean you'd need to write your script in a language which can call functions in a C library.

Answer (score 1):

You already got the right command, since all it does is evaluating the MIME Type via the `libmagic`. Its sole purpose is to recognize *file types* with *patterns* given by the respective *file format*. So you will not find anything better. You can even add own extensions for files, which don't get recognized correctly. (to magick, not the command file)